# Redirection from Http to Https works only internally on iis server browser where is app installed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-8.5

Redirection from http to https not working properly, below is my code used in web.config file

```
   <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="http to https" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Temporary" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

I have a valid SSL certificate, and I disable Require SSL.

with this code in global.asax file

```
      protected void Application_BeginRequest()
    {
        if (!Request.IsSecureConnection)
        {
            Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Replace("http://", "https://"));
        }
    }
```

I tried all argument but nothing works, **redirection works only if I open the browser from the server it self.**

Comment: 1. Always use a private tab of web browser to test. 2. Enable FRT on IIS to see what's wrong, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Comment: Your problem is that the redirect code is not working in Application_BeginRequest(), but the url rewrite rule is working, right?

Comment: Yes it's working just if I open the web site from the browser that's installed in the AWS server, but if I open it from another machine, http not be redirected automatically to https protocol.

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.

Answer (score -1):

You could do the same from the IIS Manager:

Open IIS Manager -> Select your site from Connections Panel (in left side) -> Click on HSTS... option from Action Panel(in right side) -> Check the "Enable" Option and "Redirect Http to Https" -> Now click the "OK" button.

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: Thanks anand, your suggestion works if I open the site as https first then cookies will be saved, second time I can open it as http, browser will remember me based on the saved cookie. I used iis 8.5 version. please any other suggestion!

Comment: HSTS might be helpful, but it's a mechanism to hint browsers to use HTTPS directly, not redirecting HTTP requests to HTTPS.